# Table rates don't appear in other stores

Tags: magento-1.9, multistore, shipping-methods, table-rates, ce-1.9.1.1

I am having a weird trouble whith Magento 1.9.1.1

I have imported local table rates to MAIN config and it works great on www.domain.com but when I use a different language store, the paid shipping option does not even appear and only includes free shipping module.

If I switch to default engish store, and select that other country, the paid shipping method is here and correctly calculated. This happens with all stores in other languages, de, fr, etc. Any ideas?

Comment: Make sure that rates are imported on the correct scope. They are website specific, if your stores are different websites, then you'll need to import them at every individual store.